# inheriting a model in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created a custom model (My_Model) containing all the crud functions. now i want to inherit that general model class in other models.

application/core/My_Model.php

```
<?php 

class My_Model extends CI_Model {

protected $_table;
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper("inflector");
    if(!$this->_table){
        $this->_table = strtolower(plural(str_replace("_model", "", get_class($this))));
    }
}

public function get() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    if(count($args) > 1 || is_array($args[0])) {
        $this->db->where($args[0]);
    } else {
        $this->db->where("id", $args[0]);
    }
    return $this->db->get($this->_table)->row();
}

public function get_all() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    if(count($args) > 1 || is_array($args[0])) {
        $this->db->where($args[0]);
    } else {
        $this->db->where("id", $args[0]);
    }
    return $this->db->get($this->_table)->result();
}

public function insert($data) {
    $success = $this->db->insert($this->_table, $data);
    if($success) {
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}

public function update() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    if(is_array($args[0])) {
        $this->db->where($args[0]);
    } else {
        $this->db->where("id", $args[0]);
    }
    return $this->db->update($this->_table, $args[1]);
}

public function delete() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    if(count($args) > 1 || is_array($args[0])) {
        $this->db->where($args[0]);
    } else {
        $this->db->where("id", $args[0]);
    }
    return $this->db->delete($this->_table);        
}

}

?>
```

application/models/user_model.php

```
<?php 

class User_model extends My_Model { }

?>
```

application/controllers/users.php

```
<?php 

class Users extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model("user_model");
}

function index() {

    if($this->input->post("signup")) {
        $data = array(
                "username" => $this->input->post("username"),
                "email" => $this->input->post("email"),
                "password" => $this->input->post("password"),
                "fullname" => $this->input->post("fullname")
            );
        if($this->user_model->insert($data)) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("message", "Success!");
            redirect(base_url()."users");
        }
    }
    $this->load->view("user_signup");
}

}

?>
```

when i load the controller i get an 500 internal server error but 
if i uncomment the line in controller --  $this->load->model("user_model");
then the view page loads,...cant figure out whats happening...plz help..

Comment: i have used the crud function in user_model...its working fine..but when i put all the crud functions in my_model...its not working...my_model is not being inherited in user_model..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CI config file 'application/config/config.php' find and set configuration item

`$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'My_';`

then the CI `load_class` function will load  `CI_Model` and `My_model` when calling `$ths->load->model('user_model')` in your routine;

Comment: its working fine in windows pc..dont know whats wrong with my linux system

Comment: cant figure out why the same thing is not working in linux..plz help

Comment: error reporting is on..Fatal error: Class 'My_Model' not found in /var/www/html/demo/application/models/user_model.php on line 2

Comment: May it's because of linux system is case sensitive, I made a mistake on my answer, your class name is `My_Model`, and I wrote `MY_` , so try again with `$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'My_';`